# B-frames in real-time video streaming

Tags: video, compression, streaming, h.264

Are B-frames useful (compared to P-frames) in real-time video streaming?

My intuition suggests no, as the benefit of B-frames over P-frames is that they may reference frames occuring in the future.

Therefore if a video is streaming in real-time, it won't have access to future reference frames (and it would cause the stream to pause until it had access to those frames).

Hence B-frames are no more useful than P-frames (and can be less useful if they do in fact reference future frames)

Answer (score 2):

Your theory is absolutely correct, I think.

Its worth considering, however, that the term real time tends to have a human perception element.

For example voice calls, which most people would consider real time, are generally designed to operate within a 200ms delay limit.

If this was acceptable for your video use case also, then that would give you 1/5 of a second to buffer and display the video stream which might make the forward reference encoding approach viable, depending on the frame rate and bandwidth etc.